# How to compute standard deviation with missing data with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, statistics

I am aware that SQL Server as aggregate function for STDEV and STDEVP. However, in my specific case, my table is missing data. In the table shows the inventory of a Product for every hour. When an hour is missing, it means that the inventory was 0. Let's say that I want to calculate the standard deviation of the number of product "Banana" on 2012-01-01 for the entire day, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Data

```
+---------------------+-------------+--------------+
|         Date        | ProductName | ProductCount |
+---------------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |    Banana   |    15000     |
| 2012-01-01 01:00:00 |    Banana   |    16000     |
| 2012-01-01 02:00:00 |    Banana   |    17000     |
| 2012-01-01 05:00:00 |    Banana   |    12000     |
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |    Apple    |     5000     |
| 2012-01-01 05:00:00 |    Apple    |     6000     |
+---------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE ProductInventory (
    [Date]  DATETIME,
    [ProductName] NVARCHAR(50),
    [ProductCount] INT
)

INSERT INTO ProductInventory VALUES ('2012-01-01 00:00:00', 'Banana', 15000)
INSERT INTO ProductInventory VALUES ('2012-01-01 01:00:00', 'Banana', 16000)
INSERT INTO ProductInventory VALUES ('2012-01-01 02:00:00', 'Banana', 17000)
INSERT INTO ProductInventory VALUES ('2012-01-01 05:00:00', 'Banana', 12000)
INSERT INTO ProductInventory VALUES ('2012-01-01 00:00:00', 'Apple', 5000)
INSERT INTO ProductInventory VALUES ('2012-01-01 05:00:00', 'Apple', 6000)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use a CTE function (I Let you search for that) to get the hours from 1 to 24.

But it could be easy to create an "hour table", with values 0 to 23.

Let's say you have this hours table with an hour field

```
select stdev(coalesce(pi.ProductCount, 0))
from hours h
left join ProductInventory pi on DATEPART(hh, pi.Date) = h.hour
where coalesce(pi.ProductName, 'Banana') = 'Banana'
and (pi.Date is null or (Convert(char(8), pi.Date, 112))='20120101')
```

Comment: +1 but you don't need a CTE you can use master..values instead. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d76ca/5

Answer (score 1):

```
STDEV( isnull( ProductCount , 0 ) )
```

Comment: Ok. The numbers table answer from Raphael aught to take care of the rest of the problem.  Having a "desired results" part of your example would have helped clarify the issue(s).

Answer (score 1):

Build a table of hours and `LEFT JOIN` to the Products table:

```
DECLARE @h TABLE(hr DATETIME);
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME='1/1/2012 00:00:00';
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME='1/1/2012 23:00:00';
DECLARE @HourCount INT = DATEDIFF(HOUR,@StartTime,@EndTime)+1;
DECLARE @Product VARCHAR(30) = 'Banana';

INSERT INTO @h
SELECT TOP(@HourCount) DATEADD(HOUR,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY message_id)-1,@StartTime)
FROM sys.messages;

SELECT [ProductName]=ISNULL([ProductName],@Product)
, sd=STDEV(ISNULL([ProductCount],0))
FROM @h h
LEFT JOIN ProductInventory i ON h.hr = i.[Date]
WHERE ISNULL([ProductName],@Product)=@Product
GROUP BY ISNULL([ProductName],@Product);
```

Result:

```
ProductName                                        sd
-------------------------------------------------- ----------------------
Banana                                             5763.45307123671
```

Comment: It should work for any 24h time frame specified in `@StartTime` and `@EndTime`. For that matter it should work on practically any other time frame as well.

Answer (score 1):

Generating the 0 records can be rather costly, especially when using large sets of data.  You can also use this query to run the calculation without needing to create additional records for the missing zeros:

```
select #ProductInventory.ProductName, 
    sqrt((sum(Power((DataSum / TotalDataPoints - ProductCount), 2)) + ZeroDataPoints * power(DataSum / TotalDataPoints, 2))/(TotalDataPoints-1)) stdDev,
    sqrt((sum(Power((DataSum / TotalDataPoints - ProductCount), 2)) + ZeroDataPoints * power(DataSum / TotalDataPoints, 2))/(TotalDataPoints)) stdDevP
from #ProductInventory
join
    (
    select ProductName, 
    convert(float,SUM(ProductCount)) DataSum,
    convert(float,datediff(hour, min(Date), MAX(date)) + 1) TotalDataPoints,
    convert(float,datediff(hour, min(Date), MAX(date)) + 1 - COUNT(ProductCount)) ZeroDataPoints
    from #ProductInventory
    group by ProductName
    ) Aggregates
on #ProductInventory.ProductName = Aggregates.ProductName
Group by #ProductInventory.ProductName, DataSum, TotalDataPoints, ZeroDataPoints
```

This assumes though that your first and last data points are in the set.  So if you want to use the entire 24 hour day you would have to make sure that there is at least a 0 data point added to the set for the first and the last value if it doesn't exist.  For example, in this case you could add the end of day points with this code before running the query above:

```
INSERT INTO #ProductInventory VALUES ('2012-01-01 23:00:00', 'Banana', 0)
INSERT INTO #ProductInventory VALUES ('2012-01-01 23:00:00', 'Apple', 0)
```